# How to return an object with a given value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I'm doing a search filter. I need to return the entire object containing the given actor by the user. I can find the actor, but I'm not sure how to return the object where the actor is.

JSON file:

```
{
    "title": "American Assassin",
    "year": 2017,
    "cast": [
        "Dylan O'Brien",
        "Michael Keaton",
        "Sanaa Lathan",
        "Shiva Negar",
        "Taylor Kitsch"
    ],
    "genres": []
},
{
    "title": "Mother!",
    "year": 2017,
    "cast": [
        "Jennifer Lawrence",
        "Javier Bardem",
        "Michelle Pfeiffer",
        "Domhnall Gleeson",
        "Ed Harris",
        "Kristen Wiig"
    ],
    "genres": []
}
```

My filter function:

```
checkCast(allMovies) {
      return filter(allMovies, (movie) => {
        const actor = filter(movie.cast, (actor) => {
          return actor.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.cast.toLowerCase())
        })
        console.log(actor)
        return actor
      });
    }
```

Hope everything is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the `allMovies` array by looking for an actor in the `case` array. Use `Array.some()` (or lodash `_.some()`) to return `true` if a matching actor is found.

```js
const search = { cast: 'bardem' };

function checkCast(allMovies) {
  return allMovies.filter(movie =>
    movie.cast.some(actor =>
      actor.toLowerCase().includes(search.cast.toLowerCase())
    )
  );
}

const allMovies = [{"title":"American Assassin","year":2017,"cast":["Dylan O'Brien","Michael Keaton","Sanaa Lathan","Shiva Negar","Taylor Kitsch"],"genres":[]},{"title":"Mother!","year":2017,"cast":["Jennifer Lawrence","Javier Bardem","Michelle Pfeiffer","Domhnall Gleeson","Ed Harris","Kristen Wiig"],"genres":[]}]

const result = checkCast(allMovies)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Do you know how to return not only one result. So, how to return all object which contains for instance actor name?

Comment: Filter would return multiple results, while find would return only one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#find` with `array#includes` to check if cast of movie include an actor.

```js
const movies = [{ "title": "American Assassin", "year": 2017, "cast": [ "Dylan O'Brien", "Michael Keaton", "Sanaa Lathan", "Shiva Negar", "Taylor Kitsch" ], "genres": [] }, { "title": "Mother!", "year": 2017, "cast": [ "Jennifer Lawrence", "Javier Bardem", "Michelle Pfeiffer", "Domhnall Gleeson", "Ed Harris", "Kristen Wiig" ], "genres": [] }],
      actor = 'Ed Harris',
      movie = movies.find(({cast}) => cast.includes(actor));
console.log(movie);
```

You can also do use convert actor and cast name to lower case to compare using `array#find` and `array#some`.

```js
const movies = [{ "title": "American Assassin", "year": 2017, "cast": [ "Dylan O'Brien", "Michael Keaton", "Sanaa Lathan", "Shiva Negar", "Taylor Kitsch" ], "genres": [] }, { "title": "Mother!", "year": 2017, "cast": [ "Jennifer Lawrence", "Javier Bardem", "Michelle Pfeiffer", "Domhnall Gleeson", "Ed Harris", "Kristen Wiig" ], "genres": [] }],
      actor = 'ed harris',
      movie = movies.find(({cast}) => cast.some(member => member.toLowerCase() === actor.toLowerCase()));
console.log(movie);
```